# What is Project here in highlighted Kusto query which is conversion of SQL query?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

What is `project` here in KUSTO query which is just conversion of SQL query?

I was just checking how does KUSTO query looks for any SQL query.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT operationName as Name, AVG(duration) as AvgD FROM dependencies
GROUP BY name
```

KUSTO:

```
dependencies
| summarize AvgD = avg(duration) by operationName
| project Name = operationName, AvgD
```

Does it just typo for alias change of `OperationName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no typo in the Kusto query you've included - it's a valid query, both syntactically and semantically.

That said, renaming the `operationName` column to `Name` can also be achieved as follows (which is semantically equivalent):

```
dependencies | summarize AvgD = avg(duration) by Name = operationName
```